# eval in smarty/codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty, eval, smarty3

I am trying to use one of CodeIgniter functions with smarty which the variable name is Dynamic.

normally the function is called like this :

```
{set_value(aaa, $f_aaa} <br>
```

but in my code aaa is replaced with a dynamic value

first part is easy :

```
{set_value($row->Field, $f_aaa} <br>
```

but I don't know how to use eval in smarty for this situation .

it should call the function with a loop (ex with following input/variable)

```
{set_value(name, $f_name} 

{set_value(address, $f_address}
```

**edit:** I forgot to say PHP's native `eval` function is not working inside smarty .. it's showing following error :

```
unknown function "eval"'
```

Comment: Why are you using smarty? Just use regular CI views, you can use straight up PHP code without this `eval()` monkey business. And it'll be faster too, with little impact on readability.

Answer (score 4):

`eval` is not a function - it is language construct and it cannot be called the way smarty is calling normal functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use CI helper inside Smarty, take a look at this Smarty plugin

https://github.com/fadillzzz/Smarty-CI-Helper/

It'll give you the ability to call any CI helper functions from the Smarty templates using the Smarty syntax

Answer (score 0):

have you used [{php} tag.](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php)